# Using OR and AND in conjunction

Tags: excel

I am trying to one OR and one OR/AND scenario in Excel.

I have tried multiple orders in order to get the right mix but I always either end up with Excel saying I have to many arguments or it assumes I must not be wanting to write a formula anymore :/

```
=IF(AND(OR(E2="YES",D2="YES"),(D2+E2)>0),""ANON","FIXED","BOTH")
```

Expected Result:

If E2=YES then H3 should read ANON

OR

If D2=YES then H3 should read FIXED

OR

If D2=YES AND E2=YES then H3 should read BOTH

[Image of partial excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLV38.png)

Comment: You have an extra " before "ANON"

Answer (score 1):

You need to nest the `IF`s

```
=IF(E2="Yes",IF(D2 = "Yes","BOTH","ANON"),IF(D2="Yes","FIXED","NEITHER"))
```

[image]

Comment: @DennisLaviolette if it worked for you, please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.